# Kramer's Equation at max Energy for photons is giving Intensity = 0, how is this possibe?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, nuclear-engineering, x-rays

IE = KZ(Em – E)

where IE is the intensity of photons with energy E, Z is the atomic number of the target, Em is the maximum photon energy, and K is a constant. As pointed out earlier, the maximum possible energy that a bremsstrahlung photon can have is equal to the energy of the incident electron. The maximum energy in kiloelectron volts (keV) is numerically equal to the voltage difference between the anode and the cathode in kilovolts peak (kVp)). However, the intensity of such photons is zero as predicted by the previous equation, that is, IE is ZERO when E = Em.

Kramer's Equation at max Energy for photons is giving Intensity is ZERO, how is this possibe?

Comment: intensity is a statistical concept, it needs a number of photons. If a photon has taken the maximum energy available there is no energy left to create a statistical sample that could have an intensity, so it should be zero. This  is my view of the concepts you are describing.